# Sails Js unexpexted identifier error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, sails.js

Hello I am new in sails js I am trying to CRUD using it, But I am getting unexpected error in my function index. I dont know where i am doing mistake.

```
// Usercontroller.js file



module.exports = {
    create: function (req, res) {

        if(req.method=="POST"&&req.param("User",null)!=null)
        {
            User.create(req.param("User")).done( function(err,model){
            // Error handling
            if (err) {
            res.send("Error:Sorry!Something went Wrong");
            }else {
            res.send("Successfully Created!");
            //res.redirect( ‘user/view/’+model.id);
            }
        });
        }
        else
        {
        res.render('user/create');
        }

    }

    index: function (req, res) {
        User.find().exec(function(err, users) {
            res.render( 'user/index',{'users':users});
            return;
        });

    }

    view: function (req, res) {

        var id=req.param('id',null);
        User.findOne(id).done(function(err,model){
        res.render( 'user/view',{'model':model});
        });

    }
    update: function (req, res) {

        var id=req.param("id",null);
        User.findOne(id).done(function(err, model) {

        if(req.method=="POST"&&req.param("User",null)!=null)
        {
            var usr=req.param("User",null);
            model.fname=usr.fName;
            model.mname=usr.mName;
            model.lname=usr.lName;
            model.dob=usr.dob;
            model.username=usr.Username;
            model.password=usr.password;
            model.email=usr.email;
            model.save(function(err){
            if (err) {
                res.send(“Error”);
            }else {
                res.redirect( 'user/view/'+model.id);
            }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            res.render( 'user/update',{'model':model});
        }

        });

    }

    destroy: function (req, res) {
        var id=req.param(“id”,null);
        User.findOne(id).done(function(err, usar) {
        usar.destroy(function(err) {
        res.redirect( ‘user/index/’);
        // record has been removed
        });
        });

    }
};
```

And i am getting this error in terminal while sails lift

```
/var/www/test/sailsApp/api/controllers/UserController.js:15
    index: function (req, res) {
    ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/index.js:129:29
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at requireAll (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/index.js:44:9)
    at buildDictionary (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:68:14)
    at Function.module.exports.optional (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:160:9)
    at Hook.loadControllers (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/moduleloader/index.js:241:23)
    at Hook.bound [as loadControllers] (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
    at Hook.loadAndRegisterControllers (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/controllers/index.js:63:18)
    at Hook.bound [as loadAndRegisterControllers] (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
    at Hook.initialize (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/controllers/index.js:42:9)
    at Hook.bound [as initialize] (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks i missed it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have any , after each method defined. Only the last entry of an object doesn't require a comma.

```
module.exports = {
    create: function (req, res) {

        if(req.method=="POST"&&req.param("User",null)!=null)
        {
            User.create(req.param("User")).done( function(err,model){
            // Error handling
            if (err) {
            res.send("Error:Sorry!Something went Wrong");
            }else {
            res.send("Successfully Created!");
            //res.redirect( ‘user/view/’+model.id);
            }
        });
        }
        else
        {
        res.render('user/create');
        }

    },

    index: function (req, res) {
        User.find().exec(function(err, users) {
            res.render( 'user/index',{'users':users});
            return;
        });

    },

    view: function (req, res) {

        var id=req.param('id',null);
        User.findOne(id).done(function(err,model){
        res.render( 'user/view',{'model':model});
        });

    },
    update: function (req, res) {

        var id=req.param("id",null);
        User.findOne(id).done(function(err, model) {

        if(req.method=="POST"&&req.param("User",null)!=null)
        {
            var usr=req.param("User",null);
            model.fname=usr.fName;
            model.mname=usr.mName;
            model.lname=usr.lName;
            model.dob=usr.dob;
            model.username=usr.Username;
            model.password=usr.password;
            model.email=usr.email;
            model.save(function(err){
            if (err) {
                res.send(“Error”);
            }else {
                res.redirect( 'user/view/'+model.id);
            }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            res.render( 'user/update',{'model':model});
        }

        });

    },

    destroy: function (req, res) {
        var id=req.param(“id”,null);
        User.findOne(id).done(function(err, usar) {
        usar.destroy(function(err) {
        res.redirect( ‘user/index/’);
        // record has been removed
        });
        });

    }
};
```